# Storing output of date increments in a for loop in R

Tags: r, excel, loops, store

I'm trying to create a single vector (that I plan to use in a dataframe in a similar way to an Excel column) with date increments of one day using a for loop. The idea is that the first run starts on Jan 1st, the second on Jan 2nd, the third on Jan 3rd, and so on...

I have a POSIXct variable (rdays) that contains date values for the first 45 days of the year (from Jan 1 to Feb 14) in hourly steps in the following format:

```
    [1] "2012-01-01 00:00:00 EST" "2012-01-01 01:00:00 EST" "2012-01-01 02:00:00 EST"
    [4] "2012-01-01 03:00:00 EST" "2012-01-01 04:00:00 EST" "2012-01-01 05:00:00 EST"
    [7] "2012-01-01 06:00:00 EST" "2012-01-01 07:00:00 EST" "2012-01-01 08:00:00 EST"...
```

I am using the following for-loop to create those increments:

```
    for(i in 1:321){
    range_days <- rdays + days(i) - days(1)
    a <- print(range_days)
    }

    a    # returns only the last iteration (the 321th)
```

The idea is to have all of the runs stored in a vector (or list) but I can't find a way to store them all concatenated. I need them in this format to pull data in a similar fashion to VLOOKUP in Excel to perform additional calculations.

Answer (score 1):

This is what a sapply loop is used for, something like:

```
all_results <- sapply(1:321, function(i){
    range_days <- rdays + days(i) - days(1)
    print(range_days)
    })
```

The results will have a value for each iteration in your loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Although it creates a date-numeric matrix, I was able to convert it back to a single vector in a posixct format. This is exactly what I was looking for...

Answer (score 1):

If we need to use `for` create a `list` and assign it to values

```
range_days <- vector("list", 321)
for(i in seq_len(321)){
     range_days[[i]] <- rdays + days(i) - days(1)     
}
```

Then, we convert the `list` to a `vector` (if needed) by

```
range_days <- do.call(c, range_days)
```

Comment: This works like heaven. Thank you!! Is there a way to make it work without using the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop:

Create `a` as an empty object outside the loop, then `rbind` your results to `a` inside the loop to store all iterations.

```
a=NULL

for(i in 1:321){
  range_days <- rdays + days(i) - days(1)
  a <- rbind(a,range_days)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What this creates is a numeric matrix but I need them in posixct format in a single vector. I've found something similar and was never able to  Any idea how to get there?

I'm using something like below for converting to dates but not working:

        as.POSIXct(a, format = "%y/%m/%d %H:%M", origin="1970-01-01", na.rm=TRUE)